# Issue upgrading rails 4.2 to 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

My first time trying to upgrade rails from 4.2 to 5.2 and am having an issue configuring the middleware.  To debug it I ran `rake middleware` and this was the result.  I'm not using `ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions` middleware anywhere, so I'm assuming it was turned on by default?  I was hoping to use the output from `rake middleware` to see the defaults that need to be turned off.

```
** Invoke middleware (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
No such middleware to insert after: "ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions"
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:108:in `assert_index'
```

Comment: Can you give me some more information on what steps you've taken to upgrade? What exactly have you changed?

Comment: I was following this guide after updating my rails gem to 5.2.1 https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-2-to-rails-5-0
Maybe I should upgrade to 5.0 and then upgrade 5.0 to 5.2.1?

Comment: How far in the guide did you get before this started happening?

Comment: I had gone through the whole guide and then ran into the issues, I will try upgrading to just 5.0 and test more intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

Please update **gem "airbrake"** and hope this issue will resolve because this worked for me.